# componentWillReceiveProps infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am new to react and I am wondering if this is normal or not. If I place a console.log in the componentWillReceiveProps method, it just infinitely logs information. I have a `if (this.props !== nextProps) {}` check right below the console.log so nothing actually fires off but the infinite loop concerned me as a beginner. Can someone please shed some light on if this is normal or not?

I will some of the important snippets from my code.

```
// From the parent component

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this._handleChanged = this._handleChanged.bind(this);
    this._onSave = this._onSave.bind(this);
    this.state = { columns: {}, fieldsWithErrors: {}, loaded: false, loadedValues: {} };
}

componentDidMount() {
    RestUtil.get().then((response) => {
        // put in an if statement to check if response came back null
        this.state.loadedValues = response;
        this.setState({
            loadedValues: this.state.loadedValues,
            loaded: true
        });
    }, (error: any) => {
        alert(`There was a problem submitting your request: ${error}`);
        console.log(error);
    });
}

<MyDatePicker
    label="Label"
    name="Name"
    isrequired={false}
    onSelectDate={this._handleChanged}
    value={this.state.loadedValues["Name"]}
/>

// From MyDatePicker

public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DatePicker
                    label={this.props.label}
                    strings={DayPickerStrings}
                    placeholder='Select a date...'
                    value={this.state.date}
                    isRequired={this.props.isRequired}
                    onSelectDate={this._handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: Just edited with the code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I see something wrong. I don't know if it is your pb, but : `this.setState` is asynchronous, if you fill new state with data that comes from old state, you need to use a callback : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @soywod the data isn't coming from an old state I don't think. The setState in this snippet is just overwriting a blank object of loadedValues. I guess I could have skipped the `this.state.loadedValues = response` part though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here that might be causing what you are seeing.

- **You should never set state directly outside of the constructor.** Doing `this.state.value = something` in your `componentDidMount` method is incorrect, as you should never set the state of a React component in any way other than using `setState`.
- **You should not read from state in the same method as you set it**. React's `setState` does not change the component's state immediately - state changes are batched, merged together and applied at a later point. If you want to read data from the state when it changes, you should do it in the `componentDidUpdate` method by comparing old state to new state.

If you try to change your state directly, you'll cause some issues with your component's lifecycle, which might be what is causing the infinite loop. Reading from state right after setting it might also not get you the values you expect.

Try checking out the [component lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) and refactoring your code into something more idiomatic. That might make the problem go away.